# Boost regex splitting misses last word

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to split sentence into individual words using Boost::regex.
But it is not printing the last word.
Any ideas what is wrong?

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
smatch matchResults;
regex whiteChars("(.*?)[\\s]");
string p = "This is a sentence";
for(string::const_iterator sit = p.begin(), sitend = p.end(); sit != sitend;)
{
    regex_search(sit, sitend, matchResults, whiteChars);
    if(matchResults[1].matched)
        cout << matchResults[1] << endl;
    sit = matchResults[0].second;
}
return 0;
}

Output: 
This 
is 
a
Expected Output: 
This 
is 
a
sentence
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last word is followed by `$` and not `\\s`, so your current regex - `"(.*?)[\\s]"` will not match it.

You can try out this:

```
"(.*?)(?:\\s|$)"
```

or even better, this may also work:

```
([^\\s]*)  // Just get all the non-space characters. That is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::regex rgx("\\s");
std::string p("This is a sentence");
std::regex_token_iterator current(p.begin(), p.end(), rgx, -1);
std::regex_token_iterator end;
while (current != end)
    std::cout << *current++ << '\n';
```

This should also work with Boost's regex. I haven't written that code because I'm not up on the details of Boost.